# Datos entre dos ventanas javafx

Tags: java, javafx, ventana

Estoy desarollando una javafx application, en la cual me tope con el siguiente problema:

estoy intentando llenar un formulario en el cual uno de los campos lo quiero llenar trayendo el dato desde otra ventana, en esta segunda ventana solo muestro una tableview. lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de seleccionar un registro de la tableview esta se cierre y me llene el campo de la primer ventana

Comment: [Aquí tienes varias propuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14190310/5587982), elige la que más te convenga según el contexto de tu aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

quizas debas de ser algo mas preciso en cuanto a tu caso, ya que hay diversas maneras de hacerlo dependiendo lo que busques. Segun lo que estoy entendiendo, en tu formulario tienes una especie de "pop-up" el cual se abre desde el formulario, muestra unos datos y al cerrarlo, quieres que esos datos queden reflejados en tu formulario principal.

Puedes mirar de utilizar la clase [ChoiceDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceDialog.html) o, con su mismo funcionamiento, crearte tu dialog propio haciendolo extender de [Dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html).